# Parsing RSS on Android and String Extraction

Tags: android, xml, string, xml-parsing

I'm working on porting an app from iOS to Android.  The app is just a blog app.  I would like to have the list view show just the first 7 characters from the description tag of the XML, and then when clicked, show the webpage from the XML link tag.  Any suggestions for extracting the first 7 characters and using THAT for the list view title?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max text length on your TextView to 7 characters.  You can set this in the xml with `android:maxLength` or in java with [setInputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5b%5d%29)

Comment: That worked, but had an unfortunate side effect.  Am wanting the title to be the first 7 characters of the description tag, and the maxLength worked to do that, but when we click on the row, it keeps the description at 7 characters still.  Is there a way to copy the entire string first, then limit the 7 characters on the title, and show the copy when it is clicked?